# Правильно сделать ООП

Tags: php, ооп

Привык к процедурному стилю, сейчас со скрежетом перехожу на ООП, помогите. Правильно ли я написал код так все работает, но мне кажется нужно как то по другому, суть такая, регистрация пользователя с проверкой и хешированием пароля.

Сначала хеширование пробовал в конструктор занести, но потом передумал,
сделал все в один метод. В общем помогите кто чем может, только если критика то можно конкретно, а не "твой говнокод я смотреть не стану"
вот сам класс

```
class Registration extends SqlQuery
{

    public function newArray($arr)
    {

         $end = end($arr); // извлекаю сам пароль        

         $options = [
             'cost' => 11,
         ];
         $hash = password_hash($end, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options); // создаю хеш пароля

         $new_array = array('email' => '', 'status' => '');
         $new_array = array_intersect_key($arr, $new_array);// убираю пароли из старого массива

         $hash =['password'=>$hash];

         $result = array_merge ($new_array, $hash);// создаю новый массив

         $email = $result["email"];  // извлекаю емаил 

         $sql="SELECT COUNT(id) AS id FROM ce_members WHERE `email`='".$email."'"; // проверяю нет ли такого пользователя

         $checkMember = DB::run($sql);

         $res = $checkMember->fetch();

         if($res["id"] > 0){
             $result = ['status' => 666]; 
             return $result;
        }
        else {
             return $result;
        }

    }
}
```

вот класс SqlQuery

```
<?php

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);


require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/backEnd/controller/DB.php');

class SqlQuery {

    public function InsertText($array, $nameTable) {
        // build query...
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $nameTable;

        // implode keys of $array...
        $sql .= " (`" . implode("`, `", array_keys($array)) . "`)";

        // implode values of $array...
        $sql .= " VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $array) . "') ";

        $stmt = DB::run($sql);

        $e = DB::lastInsertId();

        return $e;
    }

    public function UpdateText($array, $id, $nameTable, $tableImg) {// 1 - array with data $_POST. 2 - id by object. 3 Table by data text. 4 3 Table by data image

        $search = "SELECT `name` FROM ".$tableImg." WHERE `idParent`='".$id."'";

        $searchX = DB::run($search);
        foreach ($searchX as $file) {
           unlink($file["name"]);
        }





        $delSql = "DELETE FROM ".$tableImg." WHERE `idParent`='".$id."'";

        $delRes = DB::run($delSql);
        // build query...

        $arrVal = $array;

        $arrKey = array_keys($array);


        $all = [];

        foreach ($arrKey as $key => $val) {
            $all[] = "`" . $arrKey[$key] . "` = '" . $arrVal[$val] . "'";
        }

        $allStrong = implode(",", $all);

        $sql = "UPDATE " . $nameTable . " SET";

        $sql .= $allStrong;

        $sql .= " WHERE `id`='" . $id . "'";

        $stmt = DB::run($sql);


    }

    public function ImageInsert($id, $theName, $tableImg){

        $today = date("Y/m");
        $path =  '/backEnd/view/cms/image/' . $today;

        if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$path)) {    // проверяем если такого пути нет, то создаём новый
            mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$path, 0755, true); // новый калог с правами 
        }

        $help = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

        foreach ($_FILES[$theName]["error"] as $key_objectNewBuilds => $error_objectNewBuilds) {
            if ($error_objectNewBuilds == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $tmp_name_objectNewBuilds = $_FILES[$theName]["tmp_name"][$key_objectNewBuilds];
                // basename() может спасти от атак на файловую систему;
                // может понадобиться дополнительная проверка/очистка имени файла
                $original_name_objectNewBuilds = basename($_FILES[$theName]["name"][$key_objectNewBuilds]);
                //Получить расширение файла
                $extension_objectNewBuilds = pathinfo($original_name_objectNewBuilds, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                //Придумать новое имя файла с расширением загружаемого файла
                $new_name_objectNewBuilds = uniqid() . '.' . $extension_objectNewBuilds;
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_objectNewBuilds, "$help/$path/$new_name_objectNewBuilds");

                $name = $path . '/' . $new_name_objectNewBuilds;

                $prewSqlImg = "INSERT INTO ".$tableImg." (`idParent`, `name`) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$name."')";
                $stmt3 = DB::run($prewSqlImg);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

поля это данные POST запроса ключ=>значение

ключ всегда совпадает с столбцом в бд, а значение просто влетает в соответствующий столбец, по такому принципу строится этот класс.

DB это отсюда взял http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/pdo_wrapper там подключение к бд и запрос помогает сокращать

Comment: что за класс `SqlQuery`? Какие методы/поля из этого класса ты используешь внутри `newArray`?

Comment: @Grundy дополнил ответ

Comment: Выскажу свое лично мнение: переходить на ооп правильно, но ооп очень сильно зависит от архитектуры, чем хуже архитектура приложения тем меньше в ней ооп (это не точно, но доля правды есть). У вас тут много к чему можно придраться, а описать почему так а не так - длинно, но для первого раза не плохо :)

Comment: Например всякие ini_set не должны быть в SqlQuery, можно сказать так: один файл - одна сущность - одна задача. Файл DataBase.php - содержит в себе класс дб, и работу с ней, другой файл должен отвечать за конфигурацию вашего проекта ini_set, третий файл должен это все дело последовательно прогружать и т.д. Так-же на глаз, `Registration` выглядит стремно. Потому что помимо регистрации есть и авторизация и работа с пользователем, вы конечно можете распихать это по разным классам, но у вас там запросы. Если табличка поменяет свое название, потом ищи свищи где менять. Все должно быть в одном месте.

Comment: Нет у вас никакого ООП. Вы просто перенесли функции в методы(по сути статические)

Comment: На мой субъективный взгляд взгляд в этих примерах абсолютно бессмысленное ооп (и даже вообще не ооп, как заметили выше)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Позволю себе заметить, что использование ООП или любого другого стиля программирования без четкого понимания выгоды приводят к такого рода сомнениям. Именно практическая выгода решений должна быть мерилом правильности, а не соответствие чьим-либо рекомендациям. Людям свойственно ошибаться. Правильный код или нет, это каждый решает для себя самостоятельно исходя из поставленных задач и накопленного опыта.

На вашем месте я бы поработал с образом объектно ориентированного искусства - Yii2 фремворком (или Laravel, или Symphony).

Так вам легче будет "пощупать" преимущества и вы поймете их на уровне опыта, а не на уровне соблюдения магических ритуалов. И в итоге сможете самостоятельно отличать "хороший" код от "плохого".